# Failed upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, cannot be completed because of network connection issues

Tags: 14.04, networking, upgrade

I was upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04, but the upgrade stopped halfway through because there was not enough space on the disk.  I tried freeing up some space and upgrading again, but it still didn't work.  I then shut the computer down, and when I started it the next day, logging in would send me to a black screen and then kick me back out to the login window.  This seems to be a common problem with failed upgrades.

I tried going into the text screen to finish the upgrade, but it seems that Ubuntu cannot find any network connections.  I have ethernet and wifi connections, both of which I have confirmed to be working with another computer and on the Windows 7 OS on the same laptop that I am having issues with.

I called the `nmcli dev wifi` command from the terminal, but no connections came up.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to access the networks from the terminal, or have any ideas as to what the problem may be?

Comment: open tty mode by using ALT+Ctrl+F?. Use `sudo apt update && apt upgrade`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please switch to and log into a virtual console (Ctrl+Alt+F2) and [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -a`, `lsb_release -a`, `df -h`, `df -i`, `nmcli dev show`, `sudo apt-get update`, and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f`? See [How do I get information from the logs on my computer when I only have access to the command line?](/q/440087/175814) and/or [How can I easily share the output of a command or a text file with others?](/q/152371/175814) if you don't know how to capture and copy the information. Thanks.

Comment: If you shut down after a partial or aborted upgrade, then your system may be in an inconsistent state. Please clarify whether or not the upgrade exited due to error (return to original state), aborted or crashed during the upgrade (very bad), or gave you a 'partial upgrade' (bad). The exit message of the upgrade tool is very clear, so please try to remember accurately and don't guess.